# if __name__==function_name()

Tags: python-3.x

Why does python calls the function which is checked as **name**== function_name()

When i run this program
In this program

```
def game():
 print("1")
 return("2")
def main():
 print("game over")
if __name__==game():
 print("3")
else:
 print("4")
```

the output is:
1 # here the method game() is called and why is it so?
4
Can anyone explain the reason behind this
Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you expect `game()` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`game()` returns the string `"2"` that is not equal to the value of `__name__`, the variable which refers to the name of in scope module.

Your code is not easy to read: I suggest you to add blank lines to make clear the distinction among different function. Here is a modified version that should clarify what happens when you execute it.

```
def game():
 print("I'm: " + __name__ + " executing game()")
 print("1")
 print("I'm going to return 2")
 return("2")

def main():
    print("I'm: " + __name__ + " executing main()")
    print("game over")

print("I'm: " + __name__)
if __name__==game(): # game() is returning the string "2"
 print("3")
else:
 print("4")
```

Comment: I am just a novice so please excuse me 
i am still not able to get why the output is having 1 eventhough we are checking in if .. So can you explain it little more clearly

Comment: The test in the `if` needs to execute the `game()` function in order to check if its return value is equal to the value of ` __name__` (i.e. the string `"__main__"`). The execution of `game()` prints `1`.